# Will splotchy bleached wood stain evenly?

Tags: tabletop, refinishing

I’m trying to refinish an old oak table.

- I stripped it with Klean Strip™ premium stripper, two rounds to get all varnish off.
- Sanded with a 150 grit. Then I cleaned with mineral spirits. Then let it dry overnight.
- Then I sanded back to 120 as I wanted to bleach it, and cleaned with TSP substitute

At this point there were still some darker spots but I was sure I had gotten the varnish off so thought it might be old stain that would come off. Let that dry overnight.

- I then bleached it one round with a&b solution.
- Let it dry overnight and this morning sanded with 80 grit and then a 150.

It still looks splotchy.

I was wondering:
Do I try another bleach round for evenness?

I originally just wanted to have a lighter shade, get rid of the orange and give it a weathered look with a more grey brown stain- but the ultra dark sides and splotchy areas weren't really the effect I wanted for a rustic vibe.

[image]

Comment: A little formatting makes this much more readable. What is "a&b solution" that you bleached it with? It's not likely that anyone will provide a hard and fast rule of what the next step will be. What do you have to loose by trying another round or two of bleaching to lighten the darker areas? Maybe bleach _just_ the dark areas - you may be lightening the whole thing, making the dark areas lighter, but also lightening the light areas, leaving the same overall level of contrast. Once you've got it even enough for you, pick your refinish plan...

Comment: Hiya, welcome to StackExchange. First off I want to congratulate you on tackling this so thoroughly already, and documenting the steps well in your Q. However, your Question shouldn't have question**s** in it; every Q here should basically have just one ? in it. If you need to ask separate things about a project it is perfectly fine to ask multiple Qs to cover them — as long as a search hasn't located the answer for you, or you find that there's a previous Q&A here that covers in (no duplicates allowed).

Comment: *"but I was sure I had gotten the varnish off*" I think from a few spots that you didn't. I think the thing to try now is use a bit of stripper on the darkest spot in the middle field of the tabletop, near the bottom of the photo. If you see ANY colour come off it'll tell you straight off that there's finish remaining. Do you know the trick to *test* whether there's any finish left, by dampening the surface (with spirits, alcohol or water)? If you don't see a uniform colour change from the wood being wet it shows some finish is still in the surface wood fibres at least, if not sitting on top.

Comment: Obviously you've already wetted the surface multiple times since the last stripping but if you're not specifically on the lookout for the effect it can be missed. It's a crying shame that we consumers don't have access the methylene chloride strippers any more because although slightly hazardous they're WAY more effective than anything else bar soaking in caustic solutions. Almost all modern strippers, especially the most common ones available everywhere including Amazon, are pale shadows of MC strippers — both much, much slower and far less effective.

Answer (score 0):

> At this point there were still some darker spots but I was sure I had gotten the varnish off so thought it might be old stain that would come off.

> Do I try another bleach round for evenness?

No I don't think the table is ready for that.

Although I'm not recommending other aspects of the video specifically (or the channel itself), take a look at the really consistent colouring of the wood surfaces revealed by the use of the sander in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9eH1Q9VGqs) from Modern Makeovers, timestamps 2:49, 3:06 and 3:14. That's pretty much the level of uniformity one should be aiming for when stripping is completed<sup>1</sup>.

Now the wood in the video is something like maple or birch, both close-grained woods unlike the oak you're working with, but the same principle does apply up to a point — ideally the wood should look basically like new when you're done stripping and a modicum of scraping or sanding has been done.

With oak (also ash, chestnut, sassafras and elm) one might have to accept remaining finish left in the open grain because scraping or sanding to the bottom of it would simply remove too much wood. *This goes double if there's any veneer present*, as there appears to be in the central field of your tabletop.

**Stripping in the real world**
Stripping manufacturers don't want buyers to know this as it'll put a lot of them off, but an old standard for stripping by hand, i.e. not done by dipping (full immersion in tanks of a stripping agent) was that everything should be stripped *three times*....... Once is pretty much never enough. Two frequently leaves a little bit behind in some areas (which might or might not be removable by other means such as a scraping or a wipe with lacquer thinner or acetone). Three is sort of the sweet spot to getting the wood really pristine, at least with a really good stripper....<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Some stains that appear to be from other effects *might* still be present and require separate attention, e.g. oxalic acid for dark stains or solvent poultices for oil stains. Note that some stains can be stubborn and not respond to anything unfortunately.

<sup>2</sup> It's important to mention that because non-pros in most parts of the world are no longer allowed access to strippers based on methylene chloride (because of hand-wringing worries about consumer safety and campaigning from pressure groups) the simple fact is that most consumer-level strippers are made from less-effective chemicals. It's widely documented in user reports how *ineffective* some of these are against certain finishes or layers of finishes, requiring multiple rounds to get the job done. As a result it wouldn't be impossible to take on a job that requires stripping five times or more if there's enough finish present, or it's particularly stubborn chemically :-(